# Gatling Handling of Cache-Control headers

Tags: gatling

The response I am testing using Gatling has the following headers, which includes a `Cache-Control` header of 2 minutes.

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=120, public
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 17975 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 00:21:43 GMT
ETag: "0be271f09dc4c9a0ddea9e4b5899b59b4"
Expires: Tue, 06 Oct 2015 00:23:42 GMT
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa PSAa PSDa IVAi IVDi CONi OUR SAMo OTRo BUS PHY ONL UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA PRE"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Application-Context: application:prod
```

When using a basic simulation like so, I can easily overwhelm the servers despite being behind a Varnish server.  Is Gatling by default including a cache buster?

```
constantUsersPerSec(500) during(1 minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each virtual users has its own caches, there's no global shared one (it wouldn't make sense). Here, you're creating 500 new virtual users by second. Assuming your scenario only sends one request, you'll be hitting your server 500 times/s. Isn't it what you observe?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The RFC mentions that the max-age takes precedence: "If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive."  I'd expect each user to have it's own cache, but I'd also expect the Varnish server to always serve a cached copy as it's been instructed to cache the content for 2 minutes.

Comment: Right, sorry. Gatling properly gives max-age higher precedence over expires. Fixing my answer.

Comment: If your resource was indeed cached, I would expect a s-maxage attribute too. Are you sure about your Varnish configuration?